# Dúvida de Conceito ao cadastrar parcelas no banco de Dados

Tags: mysql

Pessoal caso eu tenha uma venda a ser cadastrada, com número de contrato, dados do clientes e entre outros e tenho campos de venda com parcelas... Ai que vem minha dúvida, devo criar uma tabela de parcelas interligada pelo número da venda e cada registro de uma venda gera vários registro de parcelas? Por exemplo realizo uma venda em 3x e cadastro 3 registros na minha tabela de parcelas interligados pelo mesmo ID da compra? Até porque preciso depois informar a data de pagamento de cada uma, se houve desconto e enfim.

Comment: Quais são suas opções? Digo, se não numa outra tabela, como você armazenaria estas informações que você já sabe que precisa?

Comment: @Caffé nao tenho opção, pergunto pois esta é a única que pensei, queria saber o que é feito hoje no "mercado".

Comment: Entendi. Considerando os requisitos que você descreveu, é feito assim mesmo como você sugeriu.

Comment: Ok! Muito obrigado @Caffé

Comment: @RafaelAssmann uma dica é lembrar de ter um controle também do valor devido. Pois muitas vezes ocorre da pessoa pagar apenas uma parte de uma parcela.

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini sim! tenho o saldo no banco de dados, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Sou desenvolvedor de sistema comerciais e sugiro o seguinte:
Como você precisa controlar o pagamento e desconto de cada uma, o ideal é criar a tabela da forma que você descreveu relacionando por ID. Sugiro ainda que você crie uma rotina para não excluir estas parcelas em caso de estorno, ou cancelamento da venda. Uma forma de fazer isto é colocar um campo "ativo" na tabela de parcelas, caso true a parcela está ativa. 
Uma estrutura básica seria:
Id, ID da Venda, Data da Parcela, Data do Pagamento, VAlor da Parcela, Valor Pago, Ativa

Outros campos seriam: status: em_cobrança_tel, em_cobrança_juridica, acordo etc

Comment: entendi perfeitamente, muito obrigado!